# how to get two column keys from one table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

table 1

```
id name 
1  Av1
2  Av2
```

table 2

```
id name1 name2
1   1      2
```

I want name according to table1.id like,

output

```
id name1 name2
1   Av1   Av2
```

Comment: Use two `JOIN`s

Comment: nothing much simple joins but nothing work because column name of table 1 is same while getting a name for table2

Comment: can you please build query? @JiriTousek

Comment: @FurqanAnsari post the query that does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to join `table1` twice, e.g.:

```
SELECT t2.id, t1.name,t11.name
FROM table2 t2 
INNER JOIN table1 t1  ON t2.name1  = t1.id
INNER JOIN table1 t11 ON t2.name2 = t11.id
```

Comment: hats off Sir.. Working great. But now how can I set WHERE clause on t2

Comment: You can just append `WHERE t2.somefield = somevalue` to the query

Comment: SELECT t2.id, t1.name, t11.name
FROM table2 t2 JOIN table1 t1 ON t2.name1 t1.id AND t2.somefeild = 10
JOIN table1 t11 ON t2.name2 = t11.id AND t2.somefeild = 10
I did this is this correct? i m getting my result perfect.

Answer (score 3):

Try it:

```
SELECT table2.id as id, t1_1.name as name1, t1_2.name as name2 FROM table2 table2
LEFT JOIN table1 t1_1  ON table2.name1 = t1_1.id
LEFT JOIN table1 t1_2  ON table2.name2 = t1_2.id
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select t2.id, n1.name as name1, n2.name as name2
from table2 t2
    left join table1 n1 on n1.id = t2.name1
    left join table1 n2 on n2.id = t2.name2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Use below query :

CREATE TABLE #tbl1( Id INT , Name VARCHAR(100))
CREATE TABLE #tbl2(  Id INT , Name1 INT, Name2 INT)

INSERT INTO #tbl1( Id  , Name )
SELECT 1,'Av1' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'Av2'

INSERT INTO #tbl2( Id  , Name1 , Name2 )
SELECT 1,1,2

SELECT T2.Id , T2.Name , T3.Name
FROM #tbl2 T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN #tbl1 T2 ON T1.Name1 = T2.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN #tbl1 T3 ON T1.Name2 = T3.Id
```